# Ошибка с библиотекой pyowm

Tags: python, pyowm

начал изучать новый для себя модуль (pyowm)
Я работаю в Pycharm
Там уже установил его (preferences -> Project interprets) 
А потом такая вот ошибка:

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM("my-key")

mg = owm.weather_manager()
obs = mg.weather_at_place('Kyiv')
print(obs.weather)

AttributeError: module 'pyowm' has no attribute 'OWM'
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема ведь в оф.документации именно такой код
Буду очень благодарен за помощь

Comment: Попробовал в Google Colab - всё работает, не ругается. У вас какая версия pyowm? Там у меня поставилась pyowm-2.10.0

Comment: Хотя нет, ругается дальше уже: AttributeError: 'OWM25' object has no attribute 'weather_manager'

Comment: с библиотекой версии 3.0 я вообще получаю: pyowm.commons.exceptions.InvalidSSLCertificateError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [примере](https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm#example) указано `from pyowm import OWM`:

```
from pyowm import OWM

owm = OWM('00ad12fa26bc6e66e81161714cea4170')

mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place('Москва')

w = observation.weather
print(w, w.wind())

>>> <pyowm.weatherapi25.weather.Weather - reference_time=2020-06-04 10:51:31+00, status=rain, detailed_status=light intensity shower rain> {'speed': 4, 'deg': 180}
```

причём забавно выходит. выше я писал комментарий, что получаю ошибку:

> pyowm.commons.exceptions.InvalidSSLCertificateError: ('Connection
>   aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно
>   разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))

стал копать, выяснил что api рабочее, ошибка возникала именно на методе получения погоды `at_place`, проверил по id, coord всё в порядке, вернулся к at_place и оно заработало. мистика